# Error on using super: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why I am getting `__init__()` takes exactly 1 argument error with the below code

```
class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.x=20
        super(ABC, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)

class DEF(object):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.y=30
        super(DEF, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)

class XYZ(ABC,DEF):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(XYZ, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)

>>> x=XYZ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(XYZ, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

>>> x=XYZ(a=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hprem/junk", line 13, in __init__
    super(XYZ, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass `self` explicitly to the superclass `__init__`.  By doing `super(XYZ, self)` you created a "bound" super object that "knows" what `self` is.  Just do `super(XYZ, self).__init__(**kwargs)` (and likewise for your other calls).

Note, though, that this class structure will fail if you pass any kwargs.  `object.__init__` doesn't accept any parameters, so you can't pass it any.  For this reason, a class that inherits directly from `object` can't safely use `super` in general (unless it explicitly calls it with no arguments, in which case there's no point in calling it at all).  It's better to create a "topmost" superclass from which `ABC` and `DEF` inherit.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the super call as suggested, fixed the issue